# How to get tag id by its name via asana api?

Tags: php, tags, asana, asana-api

I want asana tag id if i provide tag name via asana api call. Is there any method from which i can directly achieve this?

Alternative, i can get all the tags in workspace and filter through it matching with my id but this will be long process.

Any method like `getTagID(tagName)` ?? yes i can get reverse of this `getTag(tagId)`

FYI, i am using php wrapper for asana api (https://github.com/ajimix/asana-api-php-class)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [Typeahead API](https://asana.com/developers/api-reference/typeaheads) - it lets you search of items in Asana (like tags) by text. (Since you *could* have multiple tags with the same name, we can't just do `getTagID(tagName)` but this is pretty close.)

Comment: Awesome!! This i never noticed in Asana api documentation..And in my workspace i don't have multiple tags with same name so this solution is perfect for me. Thanks @agnoster :)

Answer (score 0):

Typeahead is the obvious answer, but when I'm doing bulk transforms of tasks, I find it easier to build a dictionary of known tags and their ids in the workspace with `tags.find_by_workspace()` which I can then just look up whenever required.

I have a fairly small number of tags, a lot of tasks, and no duplicate tag names, so that seems to be more efficient.